# Counting sales of different products to same customers in excel (cross sell)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a transactions table with have every client ID and product bought. One client can have bought several products, which could be stand alone products or addons.

Now I'm trying to create a cross sell table to see which addons are most common with which products, but can't figure out how to count matching multiple criteria (clientid, products and addons) in different rows.

The date table looks something like this:

```
clientid   product   ...   ...
10         prod 1    ...
11         prod 2
13         prod 1
10         addon 1
...        ...
```

And the output I want to get is:

```
x         addon 1     addon 2      addon 3 ....
prod 1       #            #            #
prod 2
prod 3
...
```

So using the example data table, the cross sell table would count 1 at prod 1 vs. addon 1 (due to clientid = 10 having bought both products)

The problem I have is counting when the same client ID matches criteria in two or more rows (the products and addons bought). The data table have almost 300k entries, so I can't do it by hand.

Anyone knows how could I do it?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You mean the relation between Addon and Product is always the same client buying both items? you should explain it more

Comment: I would do this in three steps.  `1` Make a list of unique customers. (This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only).  `2` Make columns next to the unique value list, one for every thing that a customer could have purchased.  Use **countif()** in each cell of the table to indicate whether the customer has purchased that particular product. (e.g. `COUNTIFS(A2:A5,"10",B2:B5,"prod 1")` - but substitute references to row/column headers.  `3`  Use sumproduct() to multiply columns for _product n_ with column for _addon i_

Comment: ...Actually, steps 1 and 2 could be easily combined with an instant pivot table.  Select your data, "insert->Pivot Table".  Put Client ID in the rows field, and put "Product" in both the Columns and the Values field.

Comment: @Adam thank you so much! That really does it. Just one question, since I also have almost 150 products+addons, is there anyway I can automate the search for the "product n" and "addon i" columns from the output table (product x addon) or the only way is to select each column combination manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in two steps.

1. TABLE A: Select your data, `"insert->Pivot Table"`. Put Client ID in the rows field, and put "Product" in both the Columns and the Values field.

Now you have a table with unique customers in the rows, and which product(s) &  addons each one purchased.

2. TABLE B Now make a second table with your product names in the rows and addon names in the columns.  To populate the table, use sumproduct() to multiply columns for product n with columns for addon i.

Unfortunately, I can't think of a great way to automatically select which columns in Table A the formulas in Table B should look at.  If Table A has all products followed by all addons, you could manually select each product in each row of the first column of Table B, then drag across to have it autofill the correct add-on columns from Table A.  The columns of the pivot table should be sorted alphabetically, so that may work, depending on how your products and addons are named.  You would still have to manually select all the product columns.

Comment: I solved problems similar to the one I left unsolved here using `offset` and array formulas, but they tend to run very slowly.  Perhaps that is more my fault than `offset`'s?

Comment: Thanks agains Adam. I was able to get the table to auto select the right row/column combination with indexmatch. Wouldn't have done it without your help.